# NSMutableDictionary disappears

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, viewcontroller, nsmutabledictionary

I have this weird problem, in one of my `ViewControllers` I initialize my dictionary like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  profileData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"userName":@"", 
                                                              @"userPhone":@"", 
                                                              @"userEmail":@"", 
                                                          @"userBirthDate":@""}];
}
```

It is a part of user profile view controller, which has a save button, with this handler:

```
[editProfileRequest editProfileRequest:editProfileRequestResponse 
                              userName:profileData[@"userName"] 
                             userEmail:profileData[@"userEmail"] 
                                 phone:profileData[@"userPhone"]  
                         userBirthDate:profileData[@"userBirthDate"]    
                            userGender:@""];
```

If the app is installed and launched for the first time, it crashes every time user hits save, because all the key value pairs disappear from `profileData`

On every launch after the first one everything works fine, the dictionary holds values. I have triple checked - there is no clearing of the dictionary based on the first launch condition. I assign my values for keys in the following manner:

```
profileData[@"userName"] = profileContainer.userName;
...
```

`XCode` version 7.2, iOS 9.2.1
Did anyone encounter this? Hate this black magic.

Comment: highly unlikely to be black magic... did you debug and check that the code is called? are you sure you only have 1 instance of the view controller?

Comment: what error message get when app crash?

Comment: Indeed I've encountered a lot of questions where somebody asks why the variable doesn't behave as expected, but doesn't show how they declare it, says the app crashes, but doesn't provide crash log or even point the place where the crash occurs.

Comment: In this case, the problem is obvious. No need for crash logs.

Comment: I don't know what is worse, when the person who asks or who answers thinks that the problem is obvious.

Comment: Ok, my bad. I said it's obvious because he said that dictionary is disappearing, so, I assumed that the crash log is related to the `nil` object, or something similar. @AngryHomer, could you please post the crash logs and declaration of your `profileData` iVar?

Comment: @Homer---- Use some debugging! that's the basic thing in programming world when you found some problem or issue. Your question shows lack of debugging. You could have catch the problem long before! I wonder how the OP can use the term "black magic." in Information Technology world, that really proves what kind  logic and understanding the OP have in this field.

Comment: Of course I used debugging, followed all the chain of calls and so forth. The thing is I have the exact same code in the other part of my project, which works fine. I will elaborate on black magic: some five years ago I had to write y=y in one of my projects, because after a simple comparison variable went to 0. And it fixed the problem. My profileData is declared as an instance variable. The crash occurs when I try to init another dictionary with the values from this dictionary, and they go to nil, since the dictionary has no key/values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@property(strong,retain) NSMutableDictionay *profileData;


- (void)viewWillAppear {
    [super viewWillAppear];
    profileData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:
    @{@"userName":@"", @"userPhone":@"", @"userEmail":@"",@"userBirthDate":@""}];
}
```

If you are not using ARC than you may raise a retain.

```
[profileData retain];
```

Hope this works!!

Comment: Yeah, have it enabled, even declared var with __strong.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the dictionary with convenience method, i.e. you don't have the ownership on the dictionary. You should `alloc` `init` it if you want to keep it outside of `viewDidLoad`.

P.S.: And, yes, in this particular case, there is no **BLACK MAGIC** involved.

Comment: How is it possible that I don't have ownership on the first launch, but have it on every successive?

Comment: You don't own it in either cases. It may work or not, because you are not creating the object, it's being created for you when you use convenience method. You own the object when you `alloc` `init` or `copy` the object.

Comment: There's no way to determine ownership without seeing the definition of `profileData`.

Comment: @jlehr He did mention that `profileData` is the instance variable in the comments.

Comment: Unless `profileData` is defined with a memory management semantic other than `strong`, your comment about ownership is incorrect (unless the app is compiled with ARC disabled, which wasn't mentioned in the question).

Answer (score 0):

assign the NSMutableDictionary as in your .h file

```
@property(strong,retain) NSMutableDictionay *profileData;
```

and in .m file use

```
 self.profileData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:
        @{@"userName":@"", @"userPhone":@"", @"userEmail":@"",@"userBirthDate":@""}];
```